# repository-s3 plugin not synching elasticsearch snapshots

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two elasticsearch clusters running on two separate kubernetes clusters. Both the elasticsearch clusters have the `repository-s3` plugin installed.

```
GET /_cat/plugins

    "2": {
        "name": "elasticsearch-client-575db98f7b-gd5gc",
        "component": "repository-s3",
        "version": "7.10.2"
    },
    "6": {
        "name": "elasticsearch-data-0",
        "component": "repository-s3",
        "version": "7.10.2"
    },
    "10": {
        "name": "elasticsearch-master-0",
        "component": "repository-s3",
        "version": "7.10.2"
    },
```

In one of the clusters, I am registering the `repository` in `readonly` mode, as follows:

```
PUT /_snapshot/backup_name_2_5k
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
      "base_path": "/backups/elasticsearch/backup_name_2_5k",
      "bucket": "backup",
      "region": "ap-south-1",
      "readonly": true
  }
}
```

And in another cluster in read-write mode as follows:

```
PUT /_snapshot/backup_name_2_5k
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
      "base_path": "/backups/elasticsearch/backup_name_2_5k",
      "bucket": "backup",
      "region": "ap-south-1"
  }
}
```

Both have the same repository name and the base path.

In the cluster where the repository is registered as read-write I am triggering the snapshot creation as follows:

```
PUT /_snapshot/backup_name_2_5k/backup_name_2_5k?wait_for_completion=true
{
    "indices": "vsa-*"
}
```

In the cluster **where I created the snapshot**, I see in the list the snapshot exists, and I confirmed in the s3 path the data has been written, but, in the cluster where I registered the repository as `readonly` the newly created snapshot is not showing up.

What could be the reason for this? I expect the snapshot to be listed in both the elasticsearch cluster as I use the same repository path with `readonly` flag in one of the clusters.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec_share_a_repository_across_clusters.html#:~:text=Create%20a%20custom%20repository%20that,be%20in%20the%20same%20region.&text=The%20random%20string%20bucket%20name,your%20clusters%20in%20that%20region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was how you configure your repository, the `base_path` should not start with `/` (root path)

Comment: check this thread for more details https://discuss.elastic.co/t/repository-s3-plugin-not-synching-snapshots/315117/13